# How to subset pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes based on column value (or list of values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I need to subset a large DataFrame into smaller ones specific to a name in the "Name" Column. The Names will be different each time so I took the unique values from the "Name" column and put them in a list. I was hoping to be able to use the list to subset the data. Since the names will be different each time I tried using the `groupby` function but I get a dictionary of DataFrames, however I need to be able to manipulate these further and save them as CSV files.

I have a DataFrame similar to this one:

```
data = {'Val':[8, 5, 6, 11, 33, 453, 332, 648], 'Word':["woo", "tang", "clan", "aint", "nothing", "to", "****", "with"], 'Name':["Eddie", "Jake", "Susannah", "Roland", "Roland", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    Val Word    Name
0   8   woo     Eddie
1   5   tang    Jake
2   6   clan    Susannah
3   11  aint    Roland
4   33  nothing Roland
5   453 to      Jake
6   332 ****    Jake
7   648 with    Jake
```

And I need to subset the data based on the 'Name' column to get 4 different DataFrames like these:

```
df_Jake

1   5   tang    Jake
5   453 to      Jake
6   332 ****    Jake
7   648 with    Jake
```

```
df_Roland

3   11  aint    Roland
4   33  nothing Roland
```

```
df_Eddie

0   8   woo     Eddie
```

```
df_Susannah

2   6   clan    Susannah
```

Comment: It is called groupby, i am sure it has many examples if you search for it.

Comment: The groupby method is a good choice. #wutang4eva